# Converting txt file to list and returning line after user input search

Tags: python, list, line

I'm trying to have the user input a telephone number, then the program will open a text file, convert it to a list, search the list and if the phone number is found it will return the rest of the line (which contains the address for that phone number.

I can only get it to return either "phone number not found" or the line but it does it for every single line so I end up with an output like this:

```
phone number not found
phone number not found
0121 254132 18 Springfield Road
phone number not found
phone number not found
```

---

```
for line in phonenumbers:

    if number in line:
        print (line)
    else:
        print ("phone number not found")
```

I know it's because I've put for line in phonenumbers but don't know how to not do it for every line.

Comment: Is the phone number the only data in the file

Comment: The data file looks like this:

Comment: 0121254132 18 Springfield Road

Comment: Sorry don't know how to get another line in these comments but each phone number has a street address next to it on the line, then the next line has the next phone number and street address and so on.

Comment: So there will be two kind of data one is phone number and other will be phone number not found right

Comment: No, I want it to search for the user entered phone number and if it matches, return the whole line (i.e the phone number and the address). If the user entered phone number isn't found in the text file I want it to print "phone number not found"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

```
for line in phonenumbers:    
    if number in line:
        print (line)
        break
else:
    print ("phone number not found")
```

the `else` is part of the `for` loop and will only execute if you didn't `break` out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I do this it does print the correct line but also prints "phone number not found" underneath too.

Comment: Are you sure you indented the `else` clause with the same indent as the `for` ?
And did you notice the `break` clause inside the `if`?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was being an idiot and didn't notice the break. So the break just breaks out of the loop after finding one true result? You're a star, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not just drop the else statement. It should look something like:

```
for line in phoneNumbers:
  if phone in line:
     print line
```

If you want a result in case that it was not found you could use a flag.
moreover you can just use:

```
print [line for line in phonenumbers if number in line]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to python. What's a flag?

Comment: It is not python specific that's just you set a variable to be equal to true or 1 when a certain event happens and then after the event might have happened you check the value of that variable it's called a flag since when you set that variable to 1 or true it is said that you "raise a flag". You could see that in some low level languages being used a lot as they lack another way of being notified for things but you can pretty much use it anywhere you find suitable. Since you're new to python I'd suggest that you have a look at list comprehensions they do magic stuff once you understand them!